# Display 'rd' in superscript in html option tag

Tags: html, unicode, sup

I want to show 3rd in my options tag, but the problem is 'rd' is not shown in super script.

eg,

```
<select>
<option>3<sup>rd</sup></option>
</select>
```

doesn't render 'rd' in super script and further more there is no Unicode available to represent 'r' and 'd' in super script.

Answer (score 3):

There are actually superscript chars for Unicode. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_subscripts_and_superscripts#Other_superscript_and_subscript_characters

1ˢᵗ
2ⁿᵈ
3ʳᵈ
4ᵗʰ

Unfortunately, you can't use `<sup>` in `<option>` as it won't validate.